# Having trouble displaying an array value within console.log event using .push function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

The issue here is that I have designed a basic website which takes in a users input on a form, what I then intend to do is print that value out to the console.log. however, when I check the console under developer tools in Google Chrome, all I get printed out is []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
and not the value the user has inputted.

```html
<input type="text" name="username" value="testuser">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 function error() {
    
    var error1 = [];
    var list_of_values = [];

    username_error = $('input[name="username"]').val();
    if (!username_error){
        error1.push('Fill in the username field.');
      } 
 
    console.log(error1);
 
     if (error1.length > 0){
      for(let username_error of error1){ 
       alert(username_error);
     return false;
     }
  
    }
  
     string = $('input[name="username"]').val('');
     if(string.length <= 1){
   for (let list_of_values of string){
   string.push();
   
  }
        console.log(string);

        return true;
    }

    }
error();
</script>
```

Comment: Please add you HTM as well.

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion, you can make it actually things easier with the following code.
the function below scans all input fields under fieldset  element 
 $("fieldset *[name]").each....

the issue above is multiple alert, what if you have a lot of inputs, it would alert in every input, which wont be nice for the users :) instead you can do this

```
alert(error1.toString().replace(/,/g, "\n"));
```

to alert the lists of errors at once.

string = $('input[name="username"]').val(''); 
that is actually clearing your value.. so it wont give you anything in console.log().

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="name"/><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username"/><br/><br/>
  <button onclick="error()">check</button>
</fieldset>

<script>


function error() {
    
     var error1 = [];
     var list_of_values = [];
     

   $("fieldset *[name]").each(function(){
       var inputItem = $(this);
       if(inputItem.val()) {
          return list_of_values.push(inputItem.val());
       }
       
       error1.push('Fill in the '+inputItem.attr('name')+' field!')
       
   });
 
  if(error1.length > 0) {
     console.log(error1);
     alert(error1.toString().replace(/,/g, "\n"));
  }
  if(list_of_values.length > 0) {
     console.log(list_of_values);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the `<input>` to the `input` event. When the user types anything into the `<input>` the `input` event can trigger an event handler (a function, in the demo it's `log()`).

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Reference the input
var text = document.querySelector('[name=username]');

// Register the input to the input event
text.oninput = log;

/*
Whenever a user types into the input...
Reference the input as the element being typed into
if the typed element is an input...
log its value in the console.
*/
function log(event) {
  var typed = event.target;

  if (typed.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    console.log(typed.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" value="testuser">
```